# How to design a wrapper for entities of an OData-Feed?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, odata, software-design

A customers ERP solution has (imho) a really ugly database structure. It doesn't use expressive names for neither tables nor columns. The table for Addresses for example looks like this:

```
C001_T001
=========
T001_ID
T001_F001
T001_F002
T001_F003
[...]
```

- T001_ID is the primary key
- T001_F001 stores the title
- T001_F002 stores the last name
- T001_F003 stores the fist name
- T001_F003 stores the email address
- ... you get the point

The database exposes an OData-Feed, which I can use to perform database operations.

My idea is, to create a kind of wrapper around it. So that querying the database is a bit more expressive, fun and eventually more productive.

```
// Not cool
ctx.C001_T001s.Where(x => x.T001_F002 == "Smith" && x.T001_F003 == "John")

// Cool!
Addresses.Where(x => x.LastName == "Smith" && x.FirstName == "John")
```

What are possible approaches to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SImlpe. I do that all the time.

- I Expose specific entities via Odata handcrafted to those.
- I have a data manager where I do SELECT ( new entntiy {} - I basically project uinto the new entities
- I do the where AFTER the proejction.

At least BlToolkit (my ORM on this place) is smart enough to push the where clause into the SQL statement, so I get efficient lookup and nice projections.

Comment: This project looks very interesting. I'll give it a try today.

Comment: Iti s perfect for scenarios not needing a full ORM - and odata is one (you dont update the items interactively, so a statefull cache is not needed).

Comment: I eventually changed from OData to EF, because of some [(known) limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622463.aspx#unsupportedMethods).

Comment: If you CAN do that, you ere abusing Odata to start with -your statement is like saying "i switched from HTML to SQL because of the known limitation of HTML for data inserts". OData is a front end protocol used to expose data to an external application. Entity Framework is an application internal ORM. THey serve different purposes. I could NOT replace OData with EntityFramework in any of my usages.

Comment: You're right. And the current solution is not pretty... The server which exposes the OData has now another port open, to let me connect via SQL Client. That was never planned that way.

Answer (score 1):

If the service which exposes the OData is EF based, then this should be very simple to do in EF, in the model you can rename properties and entities (as compared to the columns and tables it maps to). OData will then pickup the names from the EF.

Comment: Do I need to have a special data provider? When I use the wizard, to create the EMDX I can only choose the SQL Server as data source.

Comment: You can then go and edit the EDMX (ideally in VS, or manually) to rename the properties.

Comment: I can't continue the wizard, because I need to provide a data source. But there is no option to use OData as data source.

Comment: You can't create an EF model over OData, as noted above, if the original OData service (the one based on a real DB) is EF based, you can use this. If you need to create something like an OData proxy with rename this can't be used. Doing that it pretty hard, I don't know about an existing framework which would help you with that.

Comment: I can't change anything about the data source. And if I could, there would be dependencies on the current naming scheme. And other consumers might not like my own naming scheme.